# Remove xml nodes not in XSD schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am a C# developer tasked with writing a Java command line application which removes elements from an xml document that do not match the XSD schema definition.  If someone could give me some direction with some **simple** code that would be appreciated, I know how to do simple things like read in files etc, so just the core routines, or direction on how to do.  I suspect the solution may need recursion, but if that can be avoided it would be better.  I am coding in Eclipse if that helps

Comment: In my opinion you need to transform your existing xml (wrong one) using the XSLT to create a new xml which should be a valid xml according to the XSD.

Comment: This is a tough problem in any programming language. I'd suggest familiarising yourself with Java by writing something simpler first, so you can separate the problem of finding an algorithm from the problem of coding it in Java.

Comment: Hi Guys, I appreciate your comments, but I am only interested in an answer to my question, if you can't answer it, then  please don't comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XSLT to transform your XML into the valid XML(validated with XSD). Following article would be helpful.

[XML document processing using XSLT](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076171/java-se/xml-document-processing-in-java-using-xpath-and-xslt.html)